# WPF ValidationRules does not fire on load

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a `ValidationRules` on a textbox;

```
<TextBox Margin="5,5,5,0" Name="myTextBox" >
<Binding Path="myID" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  >
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:ValueCannotBlankValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"  />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

Now this works if the user changes the value in the textbox.  The problems that it doesn't fire on load.  Figured it would be a simple fix of changing `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` to `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"` but that causes the `ValidationRules` not to fire.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"`, the validation happens when input focus is set to another control, on the other hand, `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` fires every time the text is changed, acts much like a TextBox's TextChanged event.

`ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` ensures that the text is validated on load, your XAML code is correct. If you set a breakpoint in `ValueCannotBlankValidator.Validate` method you would probably find it is actually fired on load.

I doubt your validator returns a `valid` result at the first validation, at that moment the Text property of the TextBox is `null`, if you compare `null` against `string.Empty ("")`, you get an incorrect result.

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    ValidationResult trueResult = new ValidationResult(true, "not blank");
    string str = value as string; //value is null on load, don't compare it against ""
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return new ValidationResult(false, "blank");
    else
        return trueResult;
}
```

Comment: `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` was the one that worked for me.